# Doctrine 2 DQL CASE WHEN in Count

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have this Query in native MySQL Code

```
SELECT *
FROM `turn`
LEFT JOIN (
    poi
) ON ( turn.id = poi.turn_id )
GROUP BY turn.id
ORDER BY count( case when poi.image = 1 then 1 else null end) DESC;
```

I need to rebuild this in Doctrine 2 DQL

My attempt so far is this:

```
SELECT t, COUNT((CASE WHEN Bundle\Entity\Poi p.image = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END)) AS num
FROM Bundle\Entity\Turn t
JOIN t.pois p
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY num DESC
```

And im getting this error:

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[Syntax Error] line 0, col 99: Error: Expected end of string, got '.'") in Bundle:Admin:showTurnsFiltered.html.twig at line 75.`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error ?  How do you use your DQL statement ?

Comment: I'm using it in the class Repository, creating it there and fire it up. The error appears in my frontend. It's part of a filter function, if i'm calling this function a server error appears. Neither stacktrace nor error log provide usefull information :/

Comment: How about removing one `(` and `)` as you are using two parenthesis :/ It really seems to be a syntax problem as your query looks good.

Comment: Tried that, i'm getting the same error again, just instead of `'.'` there's a `expected FROM condition`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found it by myself after hours of trying and searching, it's working with this `DQL`:

```
$dql = 'SELECT t, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN p.image = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numImage
        FROM Bundle\Entity\Turn t
            JOIN t.pois p
        GROUP BY t.id
        ORDER BY numImage DESC';
```

Important that you need to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't work out where to put CASE, as it would not work in the ORDER clause no matter what I tried! I hope in a future version they make it possible to use in the order clause.

Comment: Worth noting you can add HIDDEN if you don't want the numImage returned in the results. `SELECT t, SUM(CASE WHEN p.image = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HIDDEN numImage`

Comment: Though replacing COUNT with SUM works in your case there seems to be a general problem with using CASE parts in DQL. I opened an issue for it here: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5915 Feel free to subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ResultSetMappingBuilder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html). It would look something like :

```
public function getTurn()
{
    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);

    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Turn', 't');
    $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Poi', 'p', 't', 'poi', array('id' => 'poi_id'));       
    $rsm->addScalarResult('ImageCount', 'ImageCount');


    $sql = 'SELECT t.id, t.foo, t.bar,
            SUM(CASE WHEN p.image = 1 then 1 else null end) ImageCount,                
            FROM Turn t   
            INNER JOIN poi p ON t.id = p.turn_id                
            ORDER BY ImageCount DESC';
    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

    return $query->getScalarResult();
}
```

**note:** you might need to change `$query->getScalarResult()`to `$query->getResult()`.

Comment: I can't use the NativeQuery because i'll send this data to a bundle which only can work with `Query` objects, but not with `NativeQuery` :-/

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I already had the NativeQuery and it was quit frustrating to see that the Bundle can't work with it, but sadly i'm forced to use it