# CASE WHEN not working doctrine2 query builder

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

I've written the following code to build the query using query builder.

```
            $em = $this->_em;
            $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->select('tbl');
            $qb->addSelect('COUNT(tbl.macId) AS totalInstallations');
            $qb->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT tbl.macId) AS uniqueInstallations');
            $qb->addSelect('COUNT(CASE  
                             WHEN tbl.updatedOn IS NOT NULL THEN tbl.macId ELSE NULL
                            END) AS totalUninstallations');
            $qb->from('Entity\SoftwareInstallation', 'tbl');
            $result = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
            return $result;
```

But it's not working in the case condition.

I get the below error:

> Type: Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
>
> Message: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 152: Error: Expected
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'
>
> Filename:
>   /var/www/html/ghostnew/application/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
>
> Line Number: 52

Answer (score -2):

Try using `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`.

See this answer: [Doctrine 2 DQL CASE WHEN in Count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24574136/1054496)

Comment: Though replacing COUNT with SUM works in your case there seems to be a general problem with using CASE parts in DQL. I opened an issue for it here: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5915 Feel free to subscribe.