# How to find the good query for IF in dql?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have some problems 
I work with doctrine and symfony.
This is my sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
le.secteur,
le.dept,
le.commune,
le.sigle,
le.rne,
le.denomination,
le.effectif,
sum(IF(b.etat = 'Toutes_periodes', b.nb, 0)) AS toutes_periodes,
sum(IF(b.etat = 'P1', b.nb, 0)) AS dont_T1,
sum(IF(b.etat = 'P2', b.nb, 0)) AS dont_T2,
sum(IF(b.etat = 'P3', b.nb, 0)) AS dont_T3,
sum(IF(b.etat = 'Cycle', b.nb, 0)) AS bilan_cycle
FROM list_etabs le
LEFT OUTER JOIN bilan b on le.rne = b.rne
GROUP BY le.secteur, le.dept, le.commune, le.sigle, le.rne
ORDER BY le.secteur, le.dept, le.commune, le.sigle, le.rne
```

This is the error in symfony 3.4

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 293: Error: Expected known function, got 'IF'
```

Have you some ideas? 
Thanks you for your help
Good day

Comment: You can try using `case .. when`, here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/24574136/1744356

Comment: ok thanks I'll try